# Would backing roaming settings with a class be elegant or Rube Goldbergesque?

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-store-apps, appsettings, roaming

I am using roaming settings to store state ASAP and restore it JIT, or ALAP (L = Late).

For the possible advantage of using data binding for properties that are accessed/mutated in this way, I'm thinking of creating a class that would mirror the roaming settings, inflating the class during the app's OnLaunched and OnResuming events with the roaming settings.

By doing this, I could bind properties to the class members, rather than have a gazillion lines of code like:

```
        textBlockPlatypus1.Text = App.roamingSettings.Values["Platypus1"].ToString();
```

Is this a stroke of genius on my part -- well, a good idea -- or would I just be overcomplicating things by adding this extra layer to something that's pretty simple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a reasonable approach.  I might suggest just serializing/deserializing whatever class you end up with and writing to a file in [RoamingFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.roamingfolder.aspx) rather than [RoamingSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.roamingsettings.aspx).  It should be pretty easy to store and retrieve in more or less a single line of code (versus individual name/value pairs via RoamingSettings).  This is essentially what the SuspensionManager does in some of the C#/XAML templates.

Be mindful or how much you are saving though, there are limits - your goal is to be able to restore the state of the application *as the user perceives it*, not necessarily save EVERYTHING, particularly if it can be reconstructed 'under the covers' when the application is re-activated.